# How to sort data in jquery fancy box data based on some particular data

Tags: jquery, jstl, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox to display list of hotels using jsp page,data contains hotel price, ratings etc after displaying data i want to add filters like search, price low to high and ratings in fancybox is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use fancybox to display your html content, but the rest is up to you. If you want to have some kind of data filtering/sorting, then you have to either use some already existing plugin designed for that (just google for "table sort", there are tons of them) or write your on your own.